# Do any philosophers value excellence per se?

Tags: aristotle

I was wondering if any philosophers value excellence as a property, regardless of the action.

Akin to aesthetic functionalism, where the functionalism in itself has value, even if the thing performing the function is evil

The closest I could find was *arete* but that seems to be more in reference to morally good activities.

Comment: I have seen a quote (not sure where) that goes something like, "It might not be nice but at least it's clever," but whether a philosophy writer said that, I don't recall.